# Does anyone know of a Thunderbolt 2 (not type C or thunderbolt 3) to usb 3 micro b cable?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, hardware, thunderbolt

I am looking to use my existing WD harddrive but use thunderbolt 2 instead of the usb3 A connection. I have looked for cables but all I find is type c ones.

Comment: Basically you want a USB hub that sits off thunderbolt 2?

Comment: Not a hub, just a straight cable connection

Comment: I answered, _then_ clicked on the duplicate link... Yep, looks like it's all been covered. :-|

Answer (score 1):

[Thunderbolt](http://www.macworld.com/article/1158145/thunderbolt_what_you_need_to_know.html) is a wholly different connection protocol from USB--it's more like external PCI-Express--so any such cable would need a USB controller built-in. It's almost certainly possible to miniaturize this into a single cable, but I doubt the demand ever existed for a commercial part to make sense; additionally, performance would still be limited by USB's capabilities. Your best bet is probably a Thunderbolt "hub", for instance this [USB and eSATA model](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HGC82ZM/A/kanex-thunderbolt-to-esata-usb-30-adapter?fnode=8b&fs=fh%3D4595%252B4506%252B401f), or a larger dock such as [this one](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HGW32VC/B/belkin-thunderbolt-2-express-hd-dock?fnode=8b&fs=fh%3D4595%252B4506%252B401f).